# Probability one random variable is less than another random variable but higher than the same other random variable with a factor

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

Consider the two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$. Assume both are uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. I want to calculate the probability that $X$ lies between some "low" linear transformation of $Y$, say $\delta_1Y$, and some "higher" linear transformation of $Y$, say $\delta_2Y$, where $\delta_1<\delta_2\Leftrightarrow\delta_1Y<\delta_2Y$. Further we know that $\delta_1>0$ and $\delta_2\geq1$. Thus, the probability I want to calculate is $\mathbb{P}(\delta_1Y<X<\delta_2Y)$.

I know that the probability that $X$ is less than $Y$ can be calculated by:

$$\mathbb{P}[X<Y]=\int_{y=0}^{1}\int_{x=0}^{y}P_{X}(x)P_{Y}(y)dxdy$$

where $P_X(x)$ is the PDF of $X$ and $P_Y(y)$ is the PDF of $Y$. A simple solution would be if you simply could calculate the probability as:

$$\mathbb{P}[\delta_{1}Y<X<\delta_{2}Y]=\mathbb{P}[\delta_{1}Y<X]\cdot\mathbb{P}[X<\delta_{2}Y]$$

But since this implicitly would assume that the two probabilities are independent, I'm pretty sure this is not a viable option. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with:

$$\begin{aligned}P\left(\delta_{1}Y<X<\delta_{2}Y\right) & =\mathbb{E}\mathbf{1}_{\delta_{1}Y<X<\delta_{2}Y}\\
 & =\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\mathbf{1}_{\delta_{1}y<x<\delta_{2}y}dxdy\\
 & =\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\max\left(0,\delta_{1}y\right)}^{\min\left(1,\delta_{2}y\right)}dxdy\\
 & =\int_{0}^{1}\min\left(1,\delta_{2}y\right)-\max\left(0,\delta_{1}y\right)dy
\end{aligned}
$$

If you already know that $\delta_1\geq0$ then $\max(0,\delta_1y)=\delta_1y$ and things become a bit easyer.

Go on with discerning cases.

Comment: Okat, thanks. I may have been a bit unclear in that regard - I will update the question accordingly. Both factors are strictly positive, and $\delta_2\geq1$, so if I understand your proposition correctly a solution to the specific problem would be:

$$P(\delta_1Y<X<\delta_2Y)=\int_0^1[min(1,\delta_2y)-\delta_1y]dy$$

How do you then treat $min(1,\delta_2y)$ in the integral?

Comment: The integral must be split up like this:$$\int_{0}^{1}\min\left(1,\delta_{2}y\right)-\delta_{1}ydy=$$$$\int_{\delta_{2}^{-1}}^{1}\min\left(1,\delta_{2}y\right)-\delta_{1}ydy+\int_{0}^{\delta_{2}^{-1}}\min\left(1,\delta_{2}y\right)-\delta_{1}ydy=$$$$\int_{\delta_{2}^{-1}}^{1}1-\delta_{1}ydy+\int_{0}^{\delta_{2}^{-1}}\delta_{2}y-\delta_{1}ydy$$That is what I mean with discerning cases.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. There is a possibility to accept the answer.

Comment: Just in a sec! I'm wondering - if thinking in terms of probability spaces, and the given distributions of $X$ and $Y$ and that $0<\delta_1<\delta_2$ - wouldn't a simpler solution not just be to subtract the probability space $P[X<\delta_1Y]$ from the strictly larger probability space $P[X<\delta_2Y]$, such that $P[\delta_1Y<X<\delta_2Y]=P[X<\delta_2Y]-P[X<\delta_1Y]$?

Comment: Yes, that would work. It might be less error prone but is not essentially different. What you apply is actually: $$\int_{0}^{1}\min\left(1,\delta_{2}y\right)-\max\left(0,\delta_{1}y\right)dy=\int_{0}^{1}\min\left(1,\delta_{2}y\right)dy-\int_{0}^{1}\max\left(0,\delta_{1}y\right)dy$$

Comment: Ah, perfect mate - thanks alot!